# Spring Expression Language: Get absolute value

Tags: java, spring, expression, spring-el

I am trying to evaluate the expression where I need to have the absolute value of operator. My expression, after evaluation, looks like this:

```
((-4.0 - 3.0)/-4.0) * 100
```

I want absolute value of denominator to be substituted there.

I have tried using Math.abs() but it throws an exception while evaluating expression having abs() in it. Here are the expressions that I have tried (and failed):

```
((-4.0 - 3.0)/${#java.lang.Math.abs(-4.0)}) * 100
((-4.0 - 3.0)/#java.lang.Math.abs(-4.0)) * 100
((-4.0 - 3.0)/${java.lang.Math.abs(-4.0)}) * 100
```

Can anyone please let me know the correct syntax for this? Also, can we use bars to get absolute value (like |-4.0| or something)?

*update*

I have tried using bars (e.g. |-4.0| but even that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`T` operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types) to invoke static methods...

```
T(java.lang.Math).abs(...)
```